# CodeIgniter template library problems

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am trying to use a template library with my current codeigniter project. However I am getting the following error message,

> Unable to load the requested file: main.php

My file system looks like this,

```
 /application  
      /themes  
        /views  
          /layouts  
             admin.php
```

In MY_Controller.php I have the following,

```
<?php
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

In my controller I have the following

```
<?php
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->template->set_layout('admin');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->template
            ->set_layout('admin') // application/views/layouts/two_col.php
            ->build('welcome_message'); // views/welcome_message
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the content of admin.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what template system your using, from the sounds of it you're using Phil Sturgeon's template library.

If so open up config/template.php

and find this line:

```
$config['layout'] = 'main';
```

And edit it as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Which template system are you using? I guess it needs a file named main.php which will load the view. Or the file does not exist and you will have to add it or the path to the file is not correct